# flutter_rust_bridge Library not loaded error when building

Tags: flutter, xcode, rust, bridge

I'm using flutter_rust_bridge to build a MacOS application. I followed the steps given by the guide.
https://cjycode.com/flutter_rust_bridge/

For some reasons, the linked dynamic libraries are not being read when set up in XCode.

it should work but when running flutter run, it gave me this error.

```
dyld[4431]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/myapp.dylib
  Referenced from: <5F6AFD84-B8E6-35AD-9E94-61418F57FA9C> /Users/jp/Documents/Projects/****/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/myapp.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/myapp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/myapp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/myapp.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

Somehow, it is not reading myapp.dylib from the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Open `macos/Runner.xcodeproj` in Xcode and go to the `$crate.xcodeproj` subproject. Select `$crate-cdylib` under *Targets* and go to the *Build Settings* tab. Then, find **Dynamic Library Install Name** and type in the path to `myapp.dylib` (it should be in `build/macos/Build/Products/<Debug or Release>/myapp.dylib`).